# SQL Server Permissions for xp_cmdshell?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I can run the following command in command prompt on `Server1` with my personal account to see the files on this other server:

```
dir \\Server2\share\folder /B /O:D-
```

However, when I run the following command from SQL server, I get "Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password":

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'dir \\Server2\share\folder /B /O:D-'
```

Notes:

- SQL Server is located on `Server1`
- I am using Windows authentication to log into SQL Server (i.e. using the same account)
- This is SQL Server 2008
- Notably, if I try to do this `dir` command for a local folder (e.g. `dir C:\`), this command works in SQL Server.

Is there some reason that I can run this command outside SQL Server, but when I try to run it inside SQL Server (from the same account), I have a permissions issue?

P.S. I know there are other ways to accomplish this, e.g. with `xp_dirtree` or other ways outside of SQL Server, but for this question I'm primarily interested in how the permissions work. The reason I was using `xp_cmdshell` in this case is because I wanted to explicitly see the error output.

---

**EDIT**

Per RBarryYoung's comment, the permissions are different. You can check specifically which account is using the command by running:

```
xp_cmdshell 'whoami'
```

Comment: Try with `EXEC master..xp_cmdshell`

Comment: @MarkoIvkovic Tried it - same result. "Logon failure: unknown username or bad password."

Comment: Won't fix the problem, but that should be `master.sys.xp_cmdshell` @MarkoIvkovic .

Comment: I must ask a basic thing, did you have access right to location?

Comment: @MarkoIvkovic Yes. As I pointed out, I can run the command from CMD directly without issue. In fact, I can also run the command from inside SQL Server with a local folder. But when I try to do it from inside SQL Server to a remote location, the command fails.

Comment: Then I think, but don't believe me, that under SQL Server domain/windows account is accessed to location. Can you set in folder properties, under Security tab that everyone is allowed `Modify` permissions and then try again?

Comment: @MarkoIvkovic Just checked the folder properties, it has permissions that everyone is allowed to modify. I reapplied permissions. No change in result.

Comment: IIRC, unless the account that your SQL Server is running under has impersonation rights, the xp_cmdshell commands will run under the server's account.  SQL Server accounts frequently (but not always) are tightly locked down and may not have the rights to access many remote resources, such as network shares.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Aha! From Microsoft's website: *When first enabled, xp_cmdshell requires CONTROL SERVER permission to execute and the Windows process created by xp_cmdshell has the same security context as the SQL Server service account.*

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889  Yes.  Before you change this, you should be aware that one of the reasons for this is as a security "firewall".  That is, so that if the SQL Server is compromised, the attacker cannot leverage it to compromise your entire network/corporation.  Otherwise, a simple SQL Injection attack could become a way to take over all of the resources in your network (I have actually demonstrated to disbelieving customers how it could be done on their SQL Servers and networks).

Comment: @RBarryYoung Yes, this is a very valid point. I will find another way.

Comment: Better question: why would you want to do this? `xp_cmdshell` is a security risk, and there is nothing you can do with it that you can't do in Powershell